# Please advise about how to I improve the execution time of this SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I improve the execution time of this SQL

```
declare   @Nemo as varchar(30)

set @Nemo = 'TELH14F'

UPDATE Nemos
SET    MPV = px,
       SaleContracts = SC
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 sum (Qty) SC,
                     Px
        FROM   marketState
        WHERE  Nemo = @Nemo
               AND side = 2
        GROUP  BY Px
        ORDER  BY px) src
WHERE  Nemo = @Nemo

UPDATE Nemos
SET    MPC = px,
       BuyContracts = SC
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 sum (Qty) SC,
                     Px
        FROM   marketState
        WHERE  Nemo = @Nemo
               AND side = 1
        GROUP  BY Px
        ORDER  BY px DESC) src
WHERE  Nemo = @Nemo
```

I have tried merging this two updates on the same table Nemos and change the "select top 1" to a MAX or MIN function with no success

**EDIT - ADDED**

I have also looked at the **execution plans** of this query, and that is the reason for me asking how to improve it

**The GOAL is that the MarketState table is only selected/read once and merge the 2 updates into a single one.**

Something similar to this

```
update Nemos SET  MPV = pxV , SaleContracts =SC, MPC = pxC, BuyContracts =BC
FROM
(Select top 1 sum (Qty) as SC, px as pxV 
from marketState where Nemo = @Nemo and side=2 
group by Px order by px ) srcA
 -- UNION ALL--
(Select top 1 sum (Qty) as BC, Px as pxC
from marketState where Nemo = @Nemo and side=1 
group by Px order by px desc ) srcB
where Nemo = @Nemo
```

How Can I avoid that UNION or make this work with a `MIN`,`MAX` aproach (keeping in mind that the column `Qty` is summed but the column `px` is not)

**THESE ARE THE TABLE AND INDEXES CREATION SCRIPTS**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nemos](
    [Nemo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExpirationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CurrentValue] [numeric](21, 5) NULL,
    [SaleContracts] [int] NULL,
    [MPV] [numeric](21, 5) NULL,
    [BuyContracts] [int] NULL,
    [MPC] [numeric](21, 5) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [ContractQuantity] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [NemoFactor] [int] NULL,
    [MinFactor] [numeric](6, 2) NULL,
    [Factor] [numeric](6, 2) NULL,
    [Delta] [numeric](6, 2) NULL,
    [TipoDelta] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ContractType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FinalTradingDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CompGroup] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TypeDelivery] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Decimals] [int] NULL,
    [BeginTradingDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [PxRef] [numeric](21, 5) NULL,
    [BuyQty] [int] NULL,
    [SaleQty] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Nemos] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [BeginTradingDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Nemos] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [LastUpdate]
GO
/****** TABLE NEMOS INDEXES ******/

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Nemos_Nemo] ON [dbo].[Nemos] 
(
    [Nemo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/***************************** marketState **************/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[marketState](
    [Nemo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OrderNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Px] [numeric](21, 5) NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [side] [int] NULL,
    [owner] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Consecutivo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_marketState] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Consecutivo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** MARKETSTATE STATE INDEXES ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[marketState] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_marketState] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Consecutivo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Nemo_Side] ON [dbo].[marketState] 
(
    [Nemo] ASC,
    [side] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Px],
[Qty]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MS_OrderNumber] ON [dbo].[marketState] 
(
    [OrderNumber] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [owner]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The core idea is to calculate the **BestBuyingPrice = MPC** and the **BestSellingPrice = MPV** for a Derivative (nemo..tecnico).

When **Side = 1** its a **BuyingOrder** and when **Side = 2** its a **SellingOrder**

When two or more orders have exactly the same price its quantities need to be added(sum)
see the image below

[image: VisualExample of calculations]

Comment: I'm not even clear what this code is doing.  "Update Nemos", but there is nothing that has an alias of "Nemos"?

Comment: try putting an index on Px

Comment: @PhilSandler - which just means that these `UPDATE`s apply to *every* row of the `Nemos` table.

Comment: @marc_s I have edited the question to add more details including the table and index creation scripts

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Yes I have looked at the execution plan and that is the reason for me asking how to improve it in the way that has been mentioned in the text that I addded

Comment: I suggest you explain in simple language what you are trying to accomplish with these two updates.

Comment: @PhilSandler I have added that to the question, please let me know what else needs to be included

Comment: why the order by clause has column Px, shouldn't you want that to be picked by sum(quantity). Also for the selling price query order by does not have DEC but for the second half Buying price query the order by clause has DESC. can you clear what is the order by column should be and does it ASC or DESC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, check if the order by column and ASC/DESC clause is right, if not update accordingly in below query.

also make sure you have updated indexes

**Table marketState:**

```
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIDX_marketState ON marketState (Px DESC,SIDE ASC,Nemo ASC)
```

**Table Nemos:**

```
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIDX_Nemos ON Nemos (Nemo ASC)
```

check the below query

```
    update t1 SET  
        MPV = pxV
        ,SaleContracts =SC
        ,MPC = pxC
        ,BuyContracts =BC
    FROM
    Nemos  t1
    JOIN
    (
        Select TOP 1 sum (Qty) as SC, px as pxV, @Nemo AS Nemo
        from marketState 
        where Nemo = @Nemo and side=2 
        group by Px
        ORDER BY px DESC    
    ) srcA
    ON srcA.Nemo=t1.Nemo
    JOIN
    (
        Select TOP 1 sum (Qty) as BC, Px as pxC, @Nemo AS Nemo
        from marketState 
        where Nemo = @Nemo and side=1 
        group by Px 
        order by px desc 
    ) srcB
        ON srcA.Nemo = srcB.Nemo
```

**EDIT:1**
as OP asked if this can be done in single read and single update here the query for that. but I do not think this will have really large difference in performance compare to the above.

Same Indexes mentioned above will work with this query as well.

```
   update t1 SET 
        MPV = q2.MPV
        ,SaleContracts =q2.SaleContracts
        ,MPC = q2.MPC
        ,BuyContracts =q2.BuyContracts
    FROM
    Nemos  t1
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT  
                SUM(CASE WHEN q1.side = 2 THEN q1.px END)   AS MPV
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN q1.side=2 THEN q1.qty END)   AS SaleContracts
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN q1.side=1 THEN px END)       AS MPC
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN q1.side=1 THEN qty END)      AS BuyContracts
                ,@Nemo AS Nemo
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  sum (Qty) as Qty,px,Side
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY side ORDER BY Px Desc) AS RowID
            from marketState 
            where Nemo = @Nemo AND side IN (1,2)
            group by Px,Side
        )q1
        WHERE q1.RowID=1
    )q2
    ON t1.nemo=q2.Nemo
```

Comment: your second option is causing an error "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 75
Column 'q1.Nemo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 86
The multi-part identifier "q1.nemo" could not be bound."

Comment: I have updated the second query as well. it was a small change moving "@Nemo AS Nemo" from inner "query Q1" to outer "query Q2"

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to only read the MarketState table once, then I would calculate your two values in one query and put these results in a temp table.  You can then do your UPDATE on Nemos table using the temp table.

Something like this...

```
    SELECT Px, Side, SUM(Qty) SC
    INTO #Results
    FROM   marketState
    WHERE  Nemo = @Nemo               
    GROUP  BY Px, Side


    UPDATE Nemos
    SET    MPV = px,
           SaleContracts = SC
    FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 (Qty) SC,
                         Px
            FROM   #Results
            WHERE side = 2
            ORDER  BY Qty) src
    WHERE  Nemo = @Nemo 

    UPDATE Nemos
    SET    MPC = px,
           SaleContracts = SC
    FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 (Qty) SC,
                         Px
            FROM   #Results
            WHERE side = 1
            ORDER  BY Qty) src
    WHERE  Nemo = @Nemo
```

Comment: P.S.  I agree with t-clausen that you should put an index on Px.

Comment: thanks for your answer but `The GOAL is that the MarketState table is only selected/read once and merge the 2 updates into a single one.`

Comment: you will need 2 select because you have two different where conditions. Side=1 other is side=2. yes, using case statement we can convert them in single query but no need to if you getting expected performance with right indexes. check my answer above.